# How do I extract the docstring of a function in a py file?

Tags: python-3.x, function, docstring

```
> file_name = python.py

> python.py
> def abc(x):
     """
     Hello World
     """
     pass
```

As you can see, inside the python.py file contains the function abc. How do I extract the docstring Hello World from it without hardcoding the function name into `help()` or `.__doc__`?

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage pydoc for docstrings documentation.

```
pydoc -w python.py
```

There are many more options available, choose the one meeting your needs.

Source - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0256/

> - [Marc-Andre Lemburg's doc.py](http://www.egenix.com/files/python/SoftwareDescriptions.html#doc.py)
> - [Daniel Larsson's pythondoc & gendoc](http://starship.python.net/crew/danilo/pythondoc/)
> - [Doug Hellmann's HappyDoc](http://happydoc.sourceforge.net/)
> - Laurence Tratt's Crystal (no longer available on the web)
> - [Ka-Ping Yee's pydoc - pydoc.py is now part of the Python standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html)
> - [Tony Ibbs' docutils](http://www.tibsnjoan.co.uk/docutils.html) - Tony has donated this name to the Docutils project - http://docutils.sourceforge.net/
> - [Edward Loper's STminus formalization and related efforts](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Eedloper/pydoc/)